# Actual methods in "evaluate expression" with IntelliJ / (node)JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea

As Javascript is a dynamically typed language, the autocomplete feature in the IntelliJ's editor doesn't work as well as with Java, and it makes sense.

However, when I'm debugging, and using "Evaluate expression", I expect to see the actual methods (not those guessed by IDEA) of an object, just like with the REPL. This is vital for me to be able to play with (and learn) nodejs.

Any workaround for this?

Thanks!

Comment: You already install [NodeJS](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6098?pr=phpStorm) plugin ?

Comment: @DozortsevAnton sure! And it works pretty good